# Issue with Datagridview checkbox column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have added a checkbox column in datagridview and adding the values for each row dynamically in datagridview

now when i click on the Datagridview to sort the first row checkbox gets unchecked automatically

> i have written code in sorted event of datagridview to bind the data again in the datagridview 
>   but still the first row checkbox column is unchecked automatically

here is my code

```
   if (attachedActiveStatus.ContainsKey(row.Cells["ServerId"].Value.ToString()))
            {

                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell1 = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[0];
                cell1.Value = true;

                row.Cells[0].Value = "true";

               row.Cells[4].Value = attachedPriority[row.Cells["ServerId"].Value.ToString()];

                switch (attachedActiveStatus[row.Cells["ServerId"].Value.ToString()])
                {
                    case "0":
                        row.Cells["Status"].Value = "Offline";

                        break;

                    case "1":
                        row.Cells["Status"].Value = "Active";

                        break;

                    case "2":
                        row.Cells["Status"].Value = "Inactive";

                        break;

                }


            }
```

Comment: can you please put your code here?

Comment: does this belong to winform or asp.net, there are more tags available ?

Comment: If you are adding as above then what/how are you binding in the sorted event, does it have value as false for the checkbox ?

Comment: this code is written in sorted event earlier when i was sorting all the dynamic rows data gets cleared  which are editable ,now after handling this code in sorted event everything is working fine but the first row  checkbox in datagridview gets unchecked

Answer (score 0):

I think that your issue may be due to the following line:

```
row.Cells[0].Value = "true";
```

This is setting the value of the checkbox again, which you have already set in the line immediately above:

```
cell1.Value = true;
```